# GUID_PK in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

When I execute this query, I am getting an error

> Cannot find data type dbo.GUID_PK

For this should I `create` table for `CandidateRoleID` or what else should I do here?

But, when I googled it I found it saying SQL Server stores `GUID`. How could I access it or what is the correct way of declaring this table? I searched in google about `GUID_PK`.

But didn't find any syntax or explanation. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl]
(
    [CandidateRoleID] [dbo].[GUID_PK] NOT NULL,
    [CandidateID]    [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RoleID]           [int] NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I think GUID_PK probably a table type. check sys.types

Comment: @bmsqldev can we give column daatatype  to be table type?.or is it custom type ?

Comment: we can define our own custom types with the data-types provided in sql server. for e.g : GUID_PK could be a user defined data type with data type uniqueidentifier. check sys.types and u can find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL server data type for a GUID is `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.

Your script should be:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl](
[CandidateRoleID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[CandidateID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[RoleID] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Tbl PRIMARY KEY (CandidateRoleID));
```

If you want it to be 'automatically' created, similar to an integer identity column, give it a default:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl](
    [CandidateRoleID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
    [CandidateID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RoleID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Tbl PRIMARY KEY (CandidateRoleID));
```

Comment: actually it is already a written code and i am trying to understand.In this they have mentioned CandidateID with [uniqueidentifier] datatype,but [CandidateRoleID] with [dbo].[GUID_PK](which looks like refering to other database).Is there some other explaination for this?.and can we use two GUID's for same table(here CandidateRoleID and CandidateID)

Comment: In which case, it sounds like it must be a custom type.  You need to have a look and see these on the original DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl](
[CandidateRoleID] [uniqueidentifier] primary key NOT NULL,
[CandidateID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[RoleID] [int] NOT NULL,
);
```

In SQL server GUID is uniqueidentifier data type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no data type 'GUID_PK' in sql server.

> GUID is an acronym for Global Unique ID(entifier) and is a unique 16
>   byte number. The term GUID and UNIQUEIDENTIFIER are often
>   interchangeable within the SQL Server community.

If you need to auto-generate `uniqueidentifier` value in your `table` during `data` `insert`, the consider adding default value to the `uniqueidentifier` data-type.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(
[CandidateRoleID] [uniqueidentifier]   NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
[CandidateID]    [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL   DEFAULT  NEWID(),
[RoleID]           [int] NOT NULL);

GO

INSERT INTO #tbl (ROLEID) SELECT  (1)

CandidateRoleID                          CandidateID                            RoleID
F20AE15E-8D97-4042-8AA8-DD7BCB0EB6D6    FAE29358-BD34-4BFE-800B-E332375E020E    1
```